# Redirect dynamic urls including querystring with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, silex

I need to redirect some urls from an old version of a web-site to new urls.
I didn't find problem with simple urls, but I can't get the urls with querystrings to work:

```
Redirect 301 /product_detail.php?id=1 http://www.mysite.com/product/permalink
```

It simply returns a 404, not found.

I'm also tried with a route on Silex (the PHP micro-framework I'm using) but it didn't work either:

```
$app->get('/product_detail.php?id={id}', function($id) use ($app) {

    $prodotto = Product::getPermalink($id);

    return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('product',array('permalink'=>$prodotto)));
});
```

Is there a way with some htaccess rule to let the query string be considered as a part of the url and let it be redirected properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Redirect 301 /product_detail.php?id=1 `http://www.mysite.com/product/permalink`

`Redirect` is a mod_alias directive not appropriate to manipulate query strings:

> mod_alias is designed to handle  simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use  the  tools provided by mod_rewrite.
>
> Extracted from [Apache mod_alias docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)

So, `mod_rewrite` should be used. The same example in one .htaccess file in root directory would be something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product_detail\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/product/permalink    [NC]
RewriteRule .*   /product/permalink       [R=301,NC,L]
```

It redirects

`http://www.mysite.com/product_detail.php?id=1`

To:

`http://www.mysite.com/product/permalink?id=1`

The query was automatically appended to the substitution URL.

For internal mapping, replace [R=301,NC,L] with [NC,L]

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer! Anyway I decided to resolve my problem with a redirect on PHP-level, that spare my .htaccess file to became a unreadable wall of text, since I have a few hundred product's page to redirect.