# How to change URLs Using rewriterules in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have URL that will be like that :

```
http://example.com/directory/index.php?q=anything
```

so that the PHP will load the test variable using $_GET['q'].

I wish to simplify this in my .htaccess to :

```
http://example.com/directory/anything.html
```

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: There's a similar question that may be of some value to you. [htaccess rewrite for query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231067/htaccess-rewrite-for-query-string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512690/redirect-dynamic-urls-including-querystring-with-htaccess

Comment: what framework are you using off?

Comment: I'm Using PHP and was able to do `http://example.com/directory/anything` to my Url. Does it affect my **SEO**. I want to do `http://example.com/directory/anything.html` **i.e., adding suffix in the end of every url.Both the above thing at the same time** Does their any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

May be you could add something like this in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ([0-9A-Za-z-\+._]+)\.html$ ./index.php?q=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Myself resolve this issue ::
here's The .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^directory/([^/]*)\.html$ /directory/index.php?q=$1 [L]
```